# which criteria is is not prioritized for selection of a feature

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence, data-analysis

I am learning ML and from there i got a question to which i am not able to understand the question is like this :

Feature selection is the process of selecting a subset of relevant features from the original set. One of the criteria given below is not prioritized for selection of a feature. Which?

1.Informative-ness

2. Being quantitative
3. Relevance
4. Non-redundancy.

Comment: My guess is Being quantitative. Because informativeness is very crucial in features selection, relevance and non-redundancy are important as well and related somehow to informativeness. However, having non-quantitative vs quantitative data should not be pivotal since non-quantitative features might be very informative and useful in explaining the target variable!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **Being quantitative**.

As long as you did the features engineering with respect to the kind of model you are using (deep-learning, linear, tree based ...), the fact that a features is qualitative or quantitative should not have any importance on the feature importance.

The others 3 are key concepts of features engineering that you'll learn during your ML-journey.

Comment: This is exactly what I said in my comment!